# Duplicate Rule is causing trigger updates to fail?

Tags: duplicate-management

Duplicate Rule is causing trigger updates to fail(DML exception stack trace is showing duplicate failure). even allow is given at duplicate rule level. Any suggestions or solution?

Comment: Are you able to post your trigger code and debug logs?

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger needs to use the [DmlOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm) class in the DML operation, specifying the duplicateRuleHeader.allowSave flag:

```
Database.DmlOptions opts = new Database.DmlOptions();
opts.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
Database.insert(records, opts);
```

(Change to whichever DML method you need).